# Eclipse egit mylyn workflow

Tags: eclipse, egit, mylyn

What is recommended workflow to work with eclipse, egit and mylyn tasks?

I have a project and I want to create multiple feature branches with corresponding mylyn tasks. The branches will be merged with the master as and when they are implemented. The problem is that mylyn doesn't switch branches on task switching.

Do I have to use either mylyn tasks or git branching? Or is there a way to use both.